# Deep Inserting data with Asp.Net WebApi + EF + Odata

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-4, odata

I'm using Odata v4 WebApi 2.2, Entity Framework 6 and  Odata v4 proxy client (WPF)
in a project.

Consider following code:

```
//Model Class
public class Order
{
    public int OrderId {get;set;} //Auto Generated Id
    public string OrderDescription {get;set;}

    Public virtual IEnumerable<OrderLine> OrderLines;
}

//Model Class
public class OrderLine
{
    public int OrderId {get;set;} //Auto Generated Id
    public int OrderLineId {get;set;} //Key of the parent entity
    public string PartDescription  {get;set;}

    Public virtual Order Order;
}


//Odata Proxy Client Code
public void insert()
{
    Order order new Order;
    order.OrderDescription = "Test Desc";

    order.Add( new OrderLine{PartDescription = P100}) //OrderId & OrderLineId is null
    order.Add( new OrderLine{PartDescription = P101})//OrderId & OrderLineId is null
    order.Add( new OrderLine{PartDescription = P101})//OrderId & OrderLineId is null

    //When save changes is called OrderId needs to be set to order lines
    Context.SaveChanges();
}
```

I need to create Order with Order lines from client and send back to database for save. The problem is The keys are auto generated in database for classes `Order` & `OrderLine`.

I need to perform a deep insert and the operation needs to be done in following sequence.

1. Order needs to be inserted first. Before inserting the Order Lines.
2. The `OrderId` of Order Lines needs to be set.
3. Order lines needs to be inserted.

Does EF or Odata V4 supports deep insert?
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deep Insert is not supported now, but you may have a work around, use $ref,

There is a example in WebAPI side:

https://github.com/xuzhg/WebApiSample/tree/eb795e26547555666410a79b88e3930d22479798/WebApiODataSample